# How to disable DHCP for ethernet connection on Pixel C

Tags: android, network-programming

I am attempting to establish point-to-point communication between a Pixel C tablet
and an embedded device.Pixel C tablet is running Marshmallow 6.0.1. I have the devices 
physically connected by USB.They will use this usb to communicate using standard web services.

In the configuration, the embedded device is acting as the "server" but unfortunately does not
support DHCP. I need to create a static IP address and disable DHCP on the tablet side.

I was able to establish an ethernet connection with LAN(DHCP) but the Pixel C does not provide the
capability to disable DHCP and modify ethernet settings.This appears to be changed for Marshmallow.

My question is, is there a procedure to create a static IP address and also disable DHCP on
the Pixel C(Marshmallow 6.0.1)? If not, can we restore the settings that were available on 
previous versions of Android?

csd

Answer (score 0):

If you long press on the network connection, you can select "Modify the network".

Then, select "Advanced Options" and "Ip parameters". Here you can choose "Static".

I did it on my Pixel C due to Wifi problems but I'm french and menus are in french.

Hope it helps
SamSam

Answer (score 0):

Need root android device:

on android phone:

```
ifconfig rndis0 192.168.42.129 up
ip route add default via 192.168.42.1 dev rndis0
iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -p udp --dport 53 -j DNAT --to 192.168.42.1:53
```

on linux pc do this:

```
ifconfig usb0 192.168.42.1 up
```